# Closed-form expression for multivariate survival function of the probability distribution itself

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, statistical-inference

Is there a closed-form expression (or simpler expression) for the survival function of the distribution itself:
$$V(z)=\int\mathbb{1}_{\{\mathbf{x}\mid p(\mathbf{x})>z\}}p(\mathbf{x})\mathrm{d}\mathbf{x}$$
where $z\in \mathbb{R}$, $\mathbf{x}\in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $p(\mathbf{x})$ is a probability distribution on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

The question is motivated by the fact that for $x\in \mathbb{R}$
$$\int F(x)\mathrm{d}F(x)=\frac{1}{2}$$
where $F(x)$ is a CDF.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "$p(\mathbf x)$ is a probability distribution on $\mathbb R^n$?" Does $p$ denote a probability density?